# Clickable Span not retaining getActivity in onClick

Tags: android, android-context

My application opens another fragment in the onclick of ClickableSpan class , the first time the fragment does open but when i rotate the device the next click of clickable span leads to a crash as getActivity() return null.

Comment: provide some code please

Comment: "when i rotate the device the next click of clickable span leads to a crash as getActivity() return null" -- however you have implemented `getActivity()` is not surviving the configuration change, apparently.